# strip the time from the date and time string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string of date and time from retrieved timestamp column of my database table

```
2015-11-21 13:20:05
```

how can I remove the "13:20:05" which is the time and retain/keep "2015-11-21" which is the date? any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date string will always be in that format, you can `split()` it by the space and take the first element of the resulting array:

```
var date = '2015-11-21 13:20:05'.split(' ')[0]; // = '2015-11-21'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use `.split()` in javascript

```
var str = "2015-11-21 13:20:05";
console.log(str.split(' ')[0]);
```

> The `split()` method is used to split a string into an array of
>   substrings, and returns the new array.
>
> Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is
>   split between each character.
>
> Note: The `split()` method does not change the original string.